# Why we use superclass type object that reference to subclass object

Tags: java, subclass, declaration, superclass

I might sound dumb asking this question or internet would have lot of reference about this question. But trust me I din't find any answer that answer properly. So I decided to ask this question

So here is 
why do we declare object this way eg
    Map m = new HashMap()
why not 
    HashMap m = new HashMap()

in general why we declare object of superclass type that reference to subclass object.

Answer (score -1):

Well, this let you to change the implementation without to relay on a specific class.

Please consider just the example you've done, we prefer to use

```
Map<String, String> m2 = new HashMap<>();
```

over

```
HashMap<String, String> m2 = new HashMap<>();
```

This let you the freedom to choose another implementation which could be more performing.

```
Map<String, String> m2 = new TreeMap<>();
```

Comment: Could I have a comment for this down vote?

Comment: Can I have a comment why you answer obvious duplicates?

Comment: Sorry but I don't get what's wrong with this answer even if it is duplicate. I see a lot of duplicate answers that are upvoted when they are pertinent. And when I was writing my answer I didn't even know that it was duplicated.

Comment: Duplicates shouldn't be answered, this just spreads knowledge and makes it way harder to maintain that knowledge. *"I see a lot of duplicate answers that are upvoted when they are pertinent"* Yes, that's a flow with many SO users who don't know what the purpose of this site is. So if you feel that your answer is important/helpful, then post it in one of the linked questions above, but not here. Thank you.

Comment: I could agree, but it let you practically impossible write an answer without to incur in a down vote, if someone found that is duplicate.

Comment: Or you search for a dupe first ... And no worries, there are just a few users who actually care about the quality of this site, so a DV for posting obivous dupes is quite rare.

Comment: I think that the fact that it is not possible add new answers when the question is marked as duplicated is enough. You should not oppress who write an answer, my opinion though.

Comment: You can write answers wherever you want, but I'm not obligated to appreciate that.

Comment: argh... :) touche